# moongose query WHERE and OR NOT

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having trouble to put together a valid query or at least query that i get correct data back with mongoose. In SQL it would be like this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 123 AND deleted_by != 1 OR deleted_by != -1;
```

Comment: Should be pretty straightforward. Can you update your question to include what you're trying?

Comment: Im tryin to get records from mongoDB. get all records with id = 123, but only those who dont have some dynamic ID or have -1 in field deleted_by

Comment: OK, can you [edit] your question to show what you're trying that isn't working? Then we can point out what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it like this.

```
conversationModel.find({
   user_to_user_from: 123,
   deleted_by: {
       $nin: [1, '-1'],
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the combination of `$or` and `$ne` like below

```
db.collection.find({ id: 123, $or: [{ deleted_by: { $ne: 1 } }, { deleted_by: { $ne: -1 } }]});
```

or with [`$nor`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nor/)

```
db.collection.find({ id: 123, $nor: [{ deleted_by: 1 }, { deleted_by: -1 }]});
```